# iOS - Initial Loading Large Amounts of Data

Tags: ios, json, ios5, core-data

I am working on a B2B app that clients will need to download a sizable chunk (504 KB) of JSON data from their servers and then locally process to JSON into core data. It's about 4000 records and it currently takes ~44 seconds to save the parsed JSON data to core data. **My issue here is not download speeds or parsing.** After this initial download there should not be more than 100 (most likely <10) new records to update. I was planning on having an initial modal screen than pops up when they launch the app and starts processing the request. Is this poor design? Since this is a B2B app our customers will most likely be ok with the initial 45sec load time but **is there a more efficient way I can design this?**

I have thought about using the JSON data directly as dictionaries and then add the local core data to the tableview as I start saving the core data on a background thread but I haven't attempted to do so yet, is this the route I should take?

Comment: parsing JSON of 504kb should not be a heavy work for iPhone 4 or above.

Comment: it's not the parsing that's the issue. it's saving the data to CoreData on the backgroud thread that takes 44.5s of the 45s

Comment: Make sure you are using JSONKit as your JSON library on the iOS side. It has been found to yield the best performance.

Comment: Sorry guys, maybe my question is misleading. I am using JSONKit and the downloading/parsing to NSDictionaries is not the issue. My question was should I show a modal view when the core data is being processed which would effectively block the rest of the app until it is complete. Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I had this same issue. Can you post the code you have for parsing it to core data? My issue was that I was saving it to the database after every record, instead of saving the core data as a whole.

Comment: @Bot Well I know I'm only saving the MOC after the entities are created in the moc because I'm using MagicRecord and I created a block method that creates the entities and saves the MOC in a completion block. The code is very encapsulated and I think it would be hard/annoying for SO users to go through all the code to create the entity (this is because there are one<->>many relationships) I will profile through that process though and see what is taking the longest. I will update if I find anything that was an error/not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it was stupid errors by my doing. I was initializing a date formatter every call and on my initial load I was running a fetch on every record to see if it existed (which obviously it doesn't) After removing date formatting I went from 45 secs to 20secs then I went from 20s to 700ms when I removed the fetching.